# Don't feel muscle soreness until after a day

Tags: muscle, squats, legs, muscle-soreness, muscle-recovery

so, I only get this with my legs (meaning my quads and hamstrings and inner thighs) and my glutes...so here is my squat routine:

120kg - 2 sets of 6 repetitions followed by 1 set of 4 (it is really hard on the third set)
80kg - 3 sets of 20 repetitions (just to warm down)

the thing is, I don't feel any form of muscle soreness for at least a day, then all of a sudden it hurts just to sit down and move any part of my lower body and I shake whilst walking :|

Why does it take that long before I fell anything? like if it was my shoulders or arms or core area, I would feel it right away. It then takes around 3-4 days for it to stop and get better, then I go back (legs and glutes - the others don't take that long to recover).

but right after the workout for up to at least a day I don't feel anything...I run and sprint and do all sorts of movements that require that lower part of my body.

Could someone please explain why it takes that long and also why is it the case for just that part of my body. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The soreness that you experience is called *Delayed Onset Muscle Soreness* (*DOMS*).

**What causes it?**

When you exercise, the muscles get damaged. That damage is a signal for the muscle to grow and get stronger. That signal stimulates inflammation. Any inflammatory process produces local pain.

**Why is it delayed?**

It takes a day or two for the training-induced muscle damage to stimulate inflammation and as such to cause the soreness.

**Why just that body part?**

There are several reasons; differing intensities between body parts, individual biomechanics etc.

The routine you posted is rather intense for the lower body. Maybe you are not pushing your upper body as hard as your legs. Especially since you are doing sprints afterwards; sprinting has similar effect as plyometric training, which causes further damage to muscle, which is already weakened after the squats. It is hard to do a similar training for the arms in terms of intensity and method.

As for why you feel it in the arms and core, maybe what you feel is exhaustion. If you feel soreness right after training, then that cannot be DOMS.